Does performing k-NN on the centroids of clusters obtained from k-means make sense mathematically?
While playing around with some text embeddings, I used k-means clustering to get 4 clusters. I also have the labels for these embeddings, and I may simply use k-NN to classify new embeddings. However, is using k-NN on 4 centroids instead of the actual data a viable modelling strategy? Does this make sense mathematically?

It depends on what you mean by "viable".
What you are doing is reducing the resolution of your embedding space. You have n embeddings that you map to 4 clusters. Label the clusters based on the most frequent label of items in the cluster. Then for inference, do KNN with new query embeddings against the 4 centroids.
In doing so, you are shifting the resolution of your inference KNN query from n to 4. KNN against centroids will perform worse than KNN against the full vector space, but also saves memory by only storing 4 centroid vectors instead of n embeddings. The viability of the centroid model depends on how much worse it performs versus the impact of the memory reduction. Whether or not that tradeoff is viable depends on your specific use case and dataset.
That said, if your motivation for doing this is reducing memory or improving query speed, you're better off looking at more developed methods like KD-trees, HNSW or Product Quantization.
